# floating an element right to its sibbling

Tags: css, css-float

I have a div which contain three elements. I floats first element right through css property float:right now i want to float the second element right to the first element and third to right to second one.

Comment: i'm trying to draw this in my head but i can't. Can you paste code?

Comment: What does this mean? `right to the first element and third to right to second one`

Comment: If I'm getting this right you float the elements right but you want to order them like if they were floated left (1,2,3 instead of 3,2,1). Can you just draw them in appropriate order?

Comment: i have a container with elements
(
a
b
c)
when i float a,b and c
this go like this
(cba)
what i want is like this
(abc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the div elements into a parent container with the `float:right;` property applied to it. You can then remove the float properties from the individual elements as they will sort, in order, naturally within the parent div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Phlume/RvJUL/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">First</div>
  <div class="div2">Second</div>
  <div class="div3">Third</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1, .div2, .div3{
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  background:#900;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;    
}
.parent{
  float:right;
  margin:auto;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background:#fff;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:inline-block;` instead of a float and use `text-align:right;` on the parent container.  Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5hFTu/1/

```
#mycontainer{
 text-align:right;   
    width:100%;
}

#mycontainer div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

The display-inline property forces the element to behave much like an image/text so you can use text-align properties to move it around.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the first element to the left and the third to the right, then the second will fall in the middle.

```
#element1 {
    float: left;
}

#element3 {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the floats respectively:

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the order of the elements in HTML. For example, if you had

```
<div class="one"> <div class="two"> <div class="three">
```

make it three two one

and add `float: right;` to each.

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hFTu/), is that what you need?

Comment: this forces OP to alter the order of the list.

Answer (score -1):

float right positions the one next to the other from right to left..you have to change the markup and do it

Or include them in a div with float:right

```
<div id="right">
  <div id="three">
  <div id="two">
  <div id="one">
</div>

#right {
  float: right;
}

#one, 
#two,
three {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: why rearrange the elements?

Comment: I didn't say it's the best solution, it's just a way to do it..I would do it the second way